# Jensen Inequality and Expected value

Tags: probability, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I am trying to proof that:

Let f $\in$ $C^2(R,R)$,$f''>0$, and $E[f(X)]=f(E[X])$.
I am trying to proof that X should be a constant.

I know that $f(E[X])\leq E[f(X)]$, this holds because of the
Jensen inequality. Which states

f($\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n \lambda_kx_k$)$\leq$ $\sum\nolimits_{k=1}^n \lambda_kf(x_k)$
If equality holds, this meanes that f is linear.
My problem now is, that if f is two times coutinously differentiable, that would mean that $f''$ should equal 0.
(i am assuming X is defined on finitely many points)

Comment: what do you mean by $C^2(R,R)$  here? Jensen's inequality works only for convex functions.

Comment: two times coutinously differentiable, and $f''$>0

Comment: If you walk through the proof of Jensen's inequality and examine which steps have inequalities, I think you can arrive to the conclusion. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1160128/43949) essentially does this.

Comment: @angryavian i used the condition that f is convex i.e. $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$, i got so far that this only holds if f is linear or if x=y. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe that if $f''>0$ then $f'$ is strictly increasing. This then [implies $f$ is strictly convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/999550/215011)